# how to create boxplots from residuals and extract the values ​in .txt of the upper and lower quartiles, and identify the values ​of the outliers?

Tags: r, regression, boxplot, outliers

as the title suggests I would like to add to my script in R, (as you can see below ), a line that allows me to plot some residual boxplots, and extract the values ​​that identify the upper quantile of the lower quantile, and the true outliers (I would like to understand beyond which values ​​the residuals are outliers)

```
enter code here
setwd("C:\\looping MAR_may2021")

file.list <- list.files(".\\input2")

for(i in file.list){
  dat <- read.csv(paste0(".\\input2\\", i), row.name=NULL)
  #use row.name=NULL when you want to repeat the same rows (in this case for TWs repeated at the bottom of the same .csv file)
  #use row.name=1 when you don't have rows repeated in the .csv files
  outname <- gsub(".csv","",i)
  
  #major axis regression RPP1 vs RPP3
  fit.sma1 <- sma(RPP3 ~ RPP1, data=dat, slope.test=1.0)
  #get and save test result 1
  sink(paste0(outname,".result.1_3.txt"))
  print(fit.sma1)
  sink()
  
  #major axis regression RPP1 vs RPP2
  fit.sma2 <- sma(RPP2 ~ RPP1, data=dat, slope.test=1.0)
  #get and save test result 2
  sink(paste0(outname,".result.1_2.txt"))
  print(fit.sma2)
  sink()
  
  #make plots
  pdf(paste0(outname,".pdf"))
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  plot(fit.sma2)
  abline(0, 1)
  plot(fit.sma2, which = "residual", col = "red", pch = 19)
  plot(fit.sma1, main = i)
  abline(0, 1)
  plot(fit.sma1, which = "residual", col = "red", pch = 19)
  dev.off()
  
  #get residuals
  resid1 <- as.data.frame(residuals(fit.sma1))
  resid2 <- as.data.frame(residuals(fit.sma2))
  
  #save residuals
  residuals <- cbind(resid1,resid2)
  row.names(residuals) <- row.names(dat)
  colnames(residuals) <- c("resid_1_3","resid_1_2")
  write.csv(residuals, paste0(outname,".residuals.csv"))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please add the output from `dput(dat)` [or `dput(head(dat))` if the data frame is large] from one iteration of your loop to your post.  This will make it easier for us to help you.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Tahnks!do you mean that I have to add an example of an output file, obtained up to the last step of the loop?@Limey